# Random Line on some 3D prints

Tags: creality-cr-6

I have been having an issue for a while now with my 3D Print that one of the layers will appear thicker than the rest.

The line artifact will be on different height level. Also not all models that I would print would have this defect some will look pretty clean.

If I print the same model again the line will appear on the same spot. I tried with different filaments on the same model same thing again.

Is this maybe a slicer issue, anything that can help with finding the cause?

Printer CR-6 SE

1. I have tried different retraction settings same result.
2. I have calibrated the extruder and have changed the extruder to dual drive.
3. I am using a Micro swiss hotend.
4. Using 2.0 Cura 5.0 Profile from CHEP & CHEP 0.28 Fast Profile.
5. Linear Advance has been calibrated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is some images of models that came out with no line present.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Dave, welcome to 3DP.SE! If you suspect the slicer to be the culprit consider to use an alternative slicer. But, since you added an image of another print object with a similar defect at a different print height (my assumption) it would rule out an issue with the hardware (e.g. lead screw or linear guides). Please describe if the other defect is at the same or different height by [edit]. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you have a defect in one of the Z-axis V roller wheels, or possibly in the lead screw, making it so that, at the point where the defect makes contact, the position is slightly deflected from where it's intended to be.

Comment: Thank you, I added some more info, the line height is different heights on different models. It will definitely be worth checking the wheels any way to diagnose a wheel? I know I can take off the screws and roll them a bit to maybe see if they are bent.

Comment: I am going to give Prusaslicer a go tonight will report back

Comment: Seems the issue went away using Prusaslicer. Spent the last two days trying to figure out new artifacts (pin holes on layer lines) after using a different slicer seems it was mostly retraction related. Producing beautiful prints once again. Thank you for the help.